# datatable not showing correct records based on filtered one

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I am using datatable with php and displaying some records, each record contain edit option with unique value inside anchor tag  to update that row but my issue is when I type some text in textbox which is provided by datatables to filter value, after filtering it is  displaying  related record but  for last column (edit)  it is unchanged.

For example I have following data uing datatable :

```
   column1      column2                               Edit

    user1      user1Data                  <a href="#" data-id="1">Edit</a>
    user2      user2Data                  <a href="#" data-id="2">Edit</a>
    user3      user3Data                  <a href="#" data-id="3">Edit</a>
    user4      user4Data                  <a href="#" data-id="4">Edit</a>
```

so when I type user4 in text box  it will show  data like   :

```
column1     column2                      Edit

user4      user4Data                  <a href="#" data-id="1">Edit</a>
```

As we can see we have record for user4 but it have  data-id= 1  i.e it is filtering record and changing two columns but not Edit column as it should be data-id=4
is it drawback of datatable?

```
<?php 

$result=$this->db->get('users')->result();

echo '<table id="myTable">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>column1</th>';
echo '<th>column2</th>';
echo '<th>Edit</th>';
</tr>';

foreach($result as $r){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$r->username.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$r->userplan.'</td>';
echo '<td value=".$r->id." >Edit</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
?>

<script>

 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: `echo '<td value=".$r->id." >Edit</td>';` is wrong, should be `echo '<td value="' . $r->id . '" >Edit</td>';` (Missing the closing/opening `'`). `echo '<th>Edit</th>';</tr>';` is also wrong, missing an `echo`

Comment: Are you sure `data-id="1"` refers to the `id` of your record and not to the position in the list? (Your data could be `user4`, `user2`, `user3` and your `data-id`s would still be 1,2,3 - according to the position)

Comment: @kerbholz ok I agree while typing missed that but I need help regarding filtered record my code is working

Comment: Yes  if I type user2,then  infront of user2 edit should contain value data-id=2 but in my case data-id=1

Comment: No idea how those Edit buttons get generated. Are they generated by DataTables? Using a plugin? Do you generate them on your own?

Comment: I am generating edit button inside foreach loop so infront of every record it will appear with that record id, please check my code

Comment: I checked that code, that's why I asked: currently, you don't generate the Edit buttons in your code, you add a table data cell with the text `Edit` in it: `echo '<td value=".$r->id." >Edit</td>';` - how are `<a href="#" data-id="4">Edit</a>` generated?

Comment: bro inside foreach loop just added simple text 'edit' so every iteration user data will show with edit text , later i will work on jquery using this edit using some class